# How to prevent URL disclosure in an AngularJS SPA?

Tags: angularjs, security, asp.net-web-api, single-page-application

A 3rd party security consultancy identified a risk in our Angular SPA/ASP.NET WebAPI application  under the area of **Information Disclosure**, which we have been told to resolve.

The risk is due to the nature of an Angular application wherein the application interface is driven by client-side javascript and URLs to sensitive areas may be discovered by looking through the JS.

EG.

```
// Inside the user-controller.js angular controller
$scope.newRecord = function () {
    $location.url('admin/users/new');
};
```

They didn't even notice our repositories which contain all the calls to endpoints on the WebAPI back end!

```
// From the user-repository.js angular service
save: function (record) {
   return $resource('api/users').save(record);
}
```

All access to endpoints are secured in the WebAPI back end and unauthorized access will be rejected. However the Security Consultancy says:

> Whilst lower privilege users would not be able to navigate to these
>   directories, the confirmation that these pages existed within the
>   application could facilitate attacks.

Traditional .NET methods of using serverside generated HTML is out of the question as the front end is a pure Angular Application with no .NET interaction aside from WebAPI calls and is language agnostic. I can only imagine creating a new angular service which calls the WebAPI for a dictionary of URLs based on their access level, but its a lot of work and added complexity.

Personally, it seems like overkill and am worried a resolution would require more effort than it's worth as we already effectively manage the security of the application.

**Question**

Is there a simple and accepted strategy for dealing with this issue in an AngularJS application? What are the best methods others have used to overcome this surly widespread "vulnerability"?

Comment: To me it sounds like an idiotic audit. What do they expect you to do, generate the JS code per user role to hide those urls, which are inaccessible to those users anyway? What are they advocating, security through obscurity? But I'm no security expert, so perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: I would basically call incompetence on the security consultancy company. They are out of touch with the current state of the industry. I'd also force them to demonstrate a successful attack based on the alleged vulnerability. This sounds to me like a group of idiots with a checklist of things to look for based on the 90s. I'm surprised they didn't claim JavaScript itself was a security risk.

Comment: I'm so relieved to hear others share my opinion. I didn't want to spell it out, but I think it's ridiculous too. This is what life is like writing software for the government where all software must pass these checklists that aren't even relevant to the software (this is only 1 of half a dozen silly issues, but the others I could at least easily resolve for them). I'll see if any security masters have some smart solutions, otherwise I'll report back to them that the effort vs gain is not worth it.

Comment: @CodeCaster that's my understanding of their expectation, to generate URLs based on access levels. I'm no security expert, either. Hopefully a security expert (with software understanding) is out there and can enlighten us or shoot this down.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you authorize access those higher-privileged endpoints using user roles, and not rely on securing your application by merely hiding them.

[Compartmentalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compartmentalization_(information_security)) is a thing. A malicious user will attack known endpoints, and if you don't expose the endpoints of APIs, chances are that they'll take longer to find those. It's comparable to hiding HTTP server version headers. Sure, an attacker may not immediately find out which version you're running, but they're going to bruteforce all known attacks applicable to various versions anyway.

So while I question the usefulness of hiding those endpoints (), a solution would be to expose an "endpoint" API, which returns a dictionary of all other endpoints:

For a regular user:

```
{
    "addresses" : "https://example.com/api/v2/address",
    "orders" : "https://example.com/api/v2/orders"
}
```

For a user in the role "accountmanagement":

```
{
    "addresses" : "https://example.com/api/v2/address",
    "orders" : "https://example.com/api/v2/orders",
    "accounts" : "https://example.com/api/v2/accounts"
}
```

For an admin:

```
{
    "addresses" : "https://example.com/api/v2/address",
    "orders" : "https://example.com/api/v2/orders",
    "accounts" : "https://example.com/api/v2/accounts",
    "users" : "https://example.com/api/v2/users"
}
```

And then from your JavaScript code, when issuing an API call, you look up the appropriate base URL for that endpoint by its key ("addresses", "users", ...) to build the request URL, or return an error when not present.

Comment: This is how I imagined doing it. I'm curious if there are any other accepted ways to handle this.

Comment: I realised that this solution does not hide the angularJS route references that were pointed out by the consultant. In fact, the angularJS routing is all in the application js file (as per standard angular practice), and hence we can't hide these routes unless we drastically change the way routing works on the client. So it wouldn't satisfy their finding (but I agree that the API "endpoints" are the more important thing to secure). I disagree with the finding as the level of change required to satisfy it would be to rewrite on a different platform all together.

Answer (score -1):

one idea I would suggest is to create a web api wrapper with all CURD methods. methods should have a parameter with service api endpoint name as value. All your javascript should call this method which resides in UI layer of your application.

your web api wrapper can inturn call the respective web api service using webClient method in server side. This way we can completely hide the web api URL.

Hope this will give you some idea.